# c# oledb exception data type mismatch occured in select query

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I'm trying to create a form to edit the datagridview which is data-bind to an access database, but when I was querying the database it threw an exception "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".                                       Here's my code/select query:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
string query = "SELECT * FROM DataServisan WHERE NomorNota=?";

conn.Open();

cmd.CommandText = query;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = nomorNota, DbType = DbType.String });

OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: "WHERE NomorNota=?"   This is not correct..!! You need to have a Value to compare in where clause

Comment: i added a parameter right there :(

Comment: My Bad - I didnt notice.... So NomorNota is a string/varchar column in DB?

Comment: it's a short text in the database (i'm using ms access)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `DbType.String` in [`OleDbType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration definition. You can use `VarChar`, `VarWChar`, `LongVarChar` or `LongVarWChar` depending on length of string value when using [`OleDbParameter` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46kb8y7x(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var parameter = new OleDbParameter("ParamName", OleDbType.VarWChar);
parameter.Value = nomorNota;
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Alternative way to define parameter value:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("ParamName", OleDbType.VarWChar);
cmd.Parameters["ParamName"].Value = nomorNota;
```

References:

[OleDbParameter Class (MSDN Docs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

[OleDbParameterCollection.Add Method (MSDN Docs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50xtbfet(v=vs.110).aspx)

[OleDbType Enumeration vs. Microsoft Access Data Types (MS Support)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320435/info-oledbtype-enumeration-vs-microsoft-access-data-types)

Comment: it still shows the exception "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" :(

Comment: Can you confirm `DataServisan` table structure and `nomorNota` value? If `nomorNota` value is not a string, use `ToString()`.

Comment: the column NomorNota in the table is a short text and the variable nomorNota is a string also i tried it from a different project and it works

Comment: Well, for `Short Text` (former `Text`) data type, try to use `OleDbType.VarWChar` as provided in reference. In what project that `DbType.String` definition works? Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: it's just a standard winforms project just as the current one I'm working on but in the other project it worked without specifying the db type

Comment: oh i've fixed by just deleting the column and readded it again thx tho